# Ubuntu Touch Architecture

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to ask if it is this:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/
only available informatiou about architecture of Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: What do you mean by "architecture of Ubuntu Touch?" I understand architecture to mean the processor type (ARM, 32/64-bit), but I don't think that's how you're using it.

Comment: For example Android architecture consist of Kernel, Application Framework, etc. and they are well described on their website so I am looking for the same information but about Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: I would assume, since Android and Ubuntu are both Linux, that they're pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ <-- a bit of information about that, plus https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/ - is this what you're looking for?